# Average Time MYSQL from a row

Tags: mysql, time, average

Hi all i have a table with the time in each row

how do i get the average time for each row with a select

eg 22:56:39 should be the result

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| Day_16              | Day_12              |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| NULL                | NULL                |
| NULL                | NULL                |
| NULL                | NULL                |
| 2011-01-16 23:52:34 | 2011-02-15 22:00:45 |
```

Ps there is a ID for each row also

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(day_16),TIME_TO_SEC(day_12))) FROM Table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Day_12) + ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Day_16) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Day_12)) / 2)) FROM tablename
```

Edit: Ulvund's solution is much cleaner